# Where are the Assertion Methods list from Django TestCase?

Tags: django, testing, assert

I googled to find the assert methods list. But it seems like this documentation is very well hidden. Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: This seems like it was inappropriately closed. There is a simple answer possible here, with facts.   It's asking for a complete list of methods. The list exists but is hard to find.  This question came up in the google search results higher than the list it's looking for.

Comment: @MarkPNeyer It might be useful but it does violate stackoverflow's question guidelines. It is a question about an external resource, not a programming question. This is an important point to follow as it would otherwise open up countless of _"Where's X?"_ kind of question. That being said, it shouldn't be taken down as this specific question seems to be quite useful to many people. But marking it as closed will show other users that these questions are actually off-topic.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

It just uses the standard python unittest, http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#assert-methods, extended with Django-specific asserts which can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#assertions).

Answer (score 8):

the link that worked for me is  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#assertions

Answer (score 5):

The django custom methods are at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#assertions